# cakephp 2.0.4 DebugKit does nothing

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I can see that the DebugKit plugin  is loaded by doing

```
        debug (CakePlugin::loaded() );
        echo CakePlugin::path('DebugKit');
```

but its not doing anything. I am not using scaffolding. Debug is set to 2. It is DebugKit v 2.0. Is there something else I am supposed to do that was left out of the documentation?
A weird thing is if I purposely put a syntax error in class DebugKitDebugger , un unstyled panel displays with the syntax error of course.

Comment: argh. Looking through the DebugKit code, I see that it looks for a body tag. I forgot my body tag in my default layout. I put that in and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug kit looks for the body tag which I did not have in my default layouts